# Why is element search is giving a cast error repeatedly?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I'm learning appium. while trying to do a simple click function on the calculator I'm getting the same error repeatedly. this is the code

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class appiumtesttwo {

static AppiumDriver<MobileElement>  driver;
    

    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            opencalculator();
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println(ex.getCause());
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        

    }
    
    public static void opencalculator() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Lenovo TB-8504X");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "HGAH50S4");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
        
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        
    
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);
        System.out.println("App started");
        
        
        
        MobileElement find = (MobileElement) driver.findElement( By.id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_8"));
        find.click();
        
        System.out.println("completed");
        }
}
```

the calculator opens but it does not click the element.

the error I'm getting is

```
null
class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to class io.appium.java_client.MobileElement (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement and io.appium.java_client.MobileElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to class io.appium.java_client.MobileElement (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement and io.appium.java_client.MobileElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at appiumtesttwo.appiumtesttwo.opencalculator(appiumtesttwo.java:54)
    at appiumtesttwo.appiumtesttwo.main(appiumtesttwo.java:22)
```

kind of frustrating as I can not learn further without solving it first. java-client version I'm using is 7.6.0 and selenium-java version is 4.0.0.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same error I am starting to loose my mind, please update if you have a solution

Comment: @Benjamin still got no clue. pls let me know if find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two problems :

- 7.6 is not compatible with 4.0.0 but only with 3.141.59 (but it doesn't matter cause it's already pointing to org.openqa.selenium and not selenium-java)
- Stop casting !!! Replace this :

```
   MobileElement find = (MobileElement) driver.findElement( By.id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_8"));
            find.click();
```

With this

```
    driver.findElement( By.id("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_8").click();
```

It worked for me !